# Is there an alternative to overloading methods in an Interface?

Tags: java, android, interface, callback, overriding

I am using an `Interface` for a `CallBack` (both of which I'm very new to). Until now, all my `CallBacks` have been of the same element type, but now I want to return a different element type.

Current situation:

```
public interface CallBack {
    void CallBack(String s)
}
```

What I thought would work:

```
public interface CallBack {
    void CallBack(String s)
    void CallBack(Integer i)
}
```

This (obviously for most of you) tells me I have to implement both methods when using the `CallBack`, which is not my intended use.
I know I could 'fix' this for now by changing it to `void CallBack(Object o)`, but I don't like the ambiguous type and would like to make it more solid.

Is there any way I can make this so my `CallBack` `Override` looks like this:

```
...new CallBack() {
    @Override
    public void CallBack(String s) {
        ...
```

... or ...

```
...new CallBack() {
    @Override
    public void CallBack(Integer i) {
        ...
```

... instead of having to implement both, or using the `Object` variant?

Comment: no, how could the code that receives the callback even know what type you want when all it sees is the `CallBack` interface. PS: is there a reaons not to have multiple different callbacks? `StringCallback`, `IntCallback`, ...?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'receives the callback'? The overridden method would know obviously, since you write that yourself, and the place where you 'call'(?) it, could know since you put that type in I guess? (`CallBack.CallBack("someString");`). Like I said, I'm very new to this

Comment: Do you mean make it generic? You could do that.

Comment: I don't think there's a reason not to have different callbacks, other then maybe preferring one file over many, especially with only 3 lines of code in them.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't know what you mean with making it generic, so.. Maybe? :P. Could you elaborate on that? -Edit: I think Radoanne Roufid just explained it.

Comment: Does the executor of the callback know what type it is?

Comment: @shmosel If by 'executor' you mean the code that calls `new CallBack() {...` etc, then yes.

Comment: @Timmiej93 Yes. You could also make it a single generic method. `<T> void CallBack(T s);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Just like Radouane Roufid suggested you mean?

Comment: @Timmiej93 Well, [yes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WontTakeYesForAnAnswer). I was answering that implicit question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use generic interface as below

```
public interface CallBack<T> {
    T CallBack(T s);
}
```

and use it as follow

```
new CallBack<String>() {

            @Override
            public String CallBack(String s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        };
```

or

```
new CallBack<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer CallBack(Integer s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }


        };
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer for me (at the moment), it seems to work in the way I want it. Thank you sir (or madam)!

Comment: @Timmiej93 Note that if you're sticking with a single interface method, you essentially have a [functional interface](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1), which means you can use a cleaner lambda syntax in Java 8. Your interface is also functionally equivalent to the built-in [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) class if you're sticking with the `void` return type. If you're using `T` as the return type, it's equivalent to [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html).

Comment: @shmosel Well I know one thing, you just overloaded my brain. I'll have to take another look at this tomorrow (1.30am).

Comment: @Timmiej93 Yeah, sorry about that. Feel free to process it at your own pace. Or ignore it for now.

Answer (score -2):

you should make your interface as generic interface by specifying a generic type parameter as below:

```
public interface Callback<T>{
     T callback(T t);
}
```

and your concrete implementations will look like below:

```
public class StringCallback implements Callback<String>{
  String callback(String  string){
    //TODO: provide your implementation here.
  }
}
```

same way you can implement your Integer version.